# how to check the two check box simultaneously in x-editable using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mean-stack, x-editable

Hi I want to check the check box if the user select the view check box it should select only view checkbox. If the user select edit checkbox it should select both view and edit checkbox simulataneously. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jbfjta1wJjLWCjdRphO7?p=preview.).

```
<td ng-click="profileform.$show()" align="center">
    <div>
        <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)"
              editable-checkbox="Manage_Rolesui.View"
              e-form="rowform"
              ng-click="profileform.$show();">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.View"
                   width="20"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
<td ng-click="profileform.$show()" align="center">
    <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)"
          ng-checked="Manage_Rolesui.Edit"
          editable-checkbox="Manage_Rolesui.Edit"
          e-form="rowform"
          ng-click="profileform.$show()">
        <input type="checkbox"
               ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.Edit"
               width="20"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngChecked` angular directive to automatically check View when Edit is checked this way :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.View" width="20"  />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.Edit" ng-change="Manage_Rolesui.View = (Manage_Rolesui.Edit === true)" width="20" />
```

Checkout the [Official ngCheck documentation for more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

*Or using a controller*

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>View</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.View" width="20"  />
    <label>Edit</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Manage_Rolesui.Edit" ng-change="autoCheckView()" width="20" />
 </div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.autoCheckView = function() {
        $scope.Manage_Rolesui.View = ($scope.Manage_Rolesui.Edit === true)
    }
}]);
```

Running example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Y79wezief0bndhah4hdF?p=preview

Comment: Yea, I thought about this solution but this does not fully match to the users requirements. If you uncheck `edit` also view gets `unchecked`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to match your needs. Pure Angular ;)

Comment: Don't put such logic into view m8.

Comment: This was the simpliest approach, but you can also use a controller method ;) Updated my answer.

Comment: Damn! you're right ! Checkout revisions of my post, I started with a controller free solution to end with a code very close to yours ! We BOTH deserve a medal ^^
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43254977/revisions

Comment: =) I think we both will not get some points here. :( But here is your Medal -> (o) <-